# jquery animation using position move of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating div's animation as http://tententen.in/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home-top').click(function() {
        $('#top').animate({
            marginTop: '50px'
        },500);
    });
    $('#home-right').click(function() {
        $('#left').animate({
            marginLeft: '-100%'
        },'fast');
        $('#right').animate({
            marginRight: '33%'
        },'fast');
    });
    $('#home-left').click(function() {
        $('#left').css({'position':'relative'}).animate({ left:'33%' },'fast');
        $('#home-container').css({ 'position': 'relative'}).animate({ left:'33%' },'fast');
        $('#right').css({'position':'relative'}).animate({ right:'-33%' },'fast');
    });
});
```

---

In my script here is only three div's. i need only left right animation..
i tried but some thing getting wrong..

http://jsbin.com/amimih/1/

Comment: you use position relative in css file and remove from this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code instead of left

```
var pos = $(this).position();
"margin-left" : pos.left or etc;
or
left : pos.left or etc;
```

and use this code instead of marginRight

```
"margin-right":"30px"
```

or you can use position:relative in css file

Comment: Sorry.. where should i change ?

Comment: @NareshKumar you can accept the answer by checking the huge-ass tick below the downvote button.

Comment: this chek for only you,because its your question,and you want chek its for me,thanks

Comment: if my answer good for you.please vote me that other peopel use this answer,thank you